# Ctree classification with weights - results displayed

Tags: r, tree, classification, party

Let's say I want to use the iris data example, but correctly classifying versicolor is 5 times more important to me.

```
library(party)
data(iris)
irisct <- ctree(Species ~ .,data = iris, weights=ifelse(iris$Species=='versicolor', 5, 1))
plot(irisct)
```

Then the tree graph changes the number of observations and conditional probabilities in each node (it multiplies versicolor by 5). Is there a way to "disable" this, i.e. show the original number of observations (total = 150 for iris)?

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enhanced reimplementation of `ctree()` in package `partykit` also has somewhat more flexible plotting capabilities. Specifically, the `node_barplot()` panel function gained a `mainlab` argument that can be used for customizing the main labels. For example for the iris data:

```
library("partykit")
ct <- ctree(Species ~ ., data = iris)
```

You can set up a vector of labels and then supply a function that accesses these:

```
lab <- paste("Foo", 1:7)
ml <- function(id, nobs) lab[as.numeric(id)]
plot(ct, tp_args = list(mainlab = ml))
```

Of course, the example above is not very meaningful but could be modified to accomplish what you want with a little bit of coding.

However, be warned about the upsampling of certain observations using the `weights` argument. The `ctree()` function really treats the `weights` as case weights and consequently the significance tests used for splitting do change. With increased number of observations, all p-values become smaller and hence the tree selects more splits (unless `mincriterion` is increased simultaneously). Compare the `ct` tree above with 4 terminal nodes with

```
ct2 <- ctree(Species ~ ., data = iris, weights = rep(2, 150))
ct3 <- ctree(Species ~ ., data = iris, weights = rep(2, 150), mincriterion = 0.999)
```

The resulting number of terminal nodes are

```
c(width(ct), width(ct2), width(ct3))
[1] 4 6 4
```

Comment: I had been try to modify `node_terminal` (with success) until I read this: 'The panel generating function node_terminal is a terse text-based representation of terminal nodes.' So what function is used for the terminal panel of `plot.party` or `plot.Binary tree`?Appears to have been `node_barplot` in this case?

Comment: The panel function `node_terminal` is used as the fallback panel function in `partykit`. When the package has been told that a tree has constant fits (means, proportions, etc.) in each leaf (by using the `constparty` class), then a graphical representation is used (boxplots for regression, barplots for classification). But `node_terminal` can also be used in that case. And, of course, you can tweak either panel function to do something specific for your purposes if you want.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Achim. It is great to finally have support for `party` from the creator himself. I was waiting for this to happen for quite a while.

Comment: Thanks, David. We'll see how this goes. I still find SO much more time intensive than R-help but decided to give it a try and see how I like the experience :-)

Comment: @felixdietrich Could you supply a gist with the modified code that worked for you? I have the same issue and this cannot be solved by passing a new `mainlab` function as the `nobs` that are passed to it are already weighted obs. It would be nicer, if there was a standard object passed to any odifiable functions that contained all information available across panels...

Comment: @MarkHeckmann, we decided against a standard object being passed around because we realized that we needed very different pieces of information in different types of panels. However, the two arguments of `mainlab` are `id` and `nobs` and via the `id` you can index any information that you stored in another object. There are already a couple of examples here in the forum - but if you post a new question I'll try to have a look.

Comment: @AchimZeileis Thanks. I will have a look if I can use the `id`to get what I want. I posted another question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784109/add-horizontal-line-to-terminal-barplots-in-party-partykit-trees), which is only loosely connected, though...

Comment: @MarkHeckmann: As for pre-computing information and then accessing it via the node ID, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356122/displaying-inference-tree-node-values-with-print/33358470. (This is not about the `mainlab` argument but the idea is similar.) And as for your other question: I've tried to answer it now.