# Displaying inference tree node values with "print"

Tags: r, party

I apologize in advance if I butcher this question as I'm very new to R and statistical analysis in general.

I've generated a conditional inference tree using the `party` library.
When I `plot(my_tree, type = "simple")` I get a result like this:

[image: R tree plot]

When I `print(my_tree)` I get a result like this:

```
1) SOME_VALUE <= 2.5; criterion = 1, statistic = 1306.478
  2) SOME_VALUE <= -10.5; criterion = 1, statistic = 173.416
    3) SOME_VALUE <= -16; criterion = 1, statistic = 19.385
      4)*  weights = 275 
    3) SOME_VALUE > -16
      5)*  weights = 261 
  2) SOME_VALUE > -10.5
    6) SOME_VALUE <= -2.5; criterion = 1, statistic = 24.094
      7) SOME_VALUE <= -6.5; criterion = 0.974, statistic = 4.989
        8)*  weights = 346 
      7) SOME_VALUE > -6.5
        9)*  weights = 563 
    6) SOME_VALUE > -2.5
      10)*  weights = 442 
1) SOME_VALUE > 2.5
  11) SOME_VALUE <= 10; criterion = 1, statistic = 225.148
    12) SOME_VALUE <= 6.5; criterion = 1, statistic = 18.789
      13)*  weights = 648 
    12) SOME_VALUE > 6.5
      14)*  weights = 473 
  11) SOME_VALUE > 10
    15) SOME_VALUE <= 16; criterion = 1, statistic = 51.729
      16)*  weights = 595 
    15) SOME_VALUE > 16
      17) SOME_VALUE <= 23.5; criterion = 0.997, statistic = 8.931
        18)*  weights = 488 
      17) SOME_VALUE > 23.5
        19)*  weights = 365
```

I prefer the output of `print`, but it seems to be lacking the `y = (0.96, 0.04)` values.

Ideally, I would like my output to look something like this:

```
1) SOME_VALUE <= 2.5; criterion = 1, statistic = 1306.478
  2) SOME_VALUE <= -10.5; criterion = 1, statistic = 173.416
    3) SOME_VALUE <= -16; criterion = 1, statistic = 19.385
      4)*  weights = 275; y = (0.96, 0.04)
    3) SOME_VALUE > -16
      5)*  weights = 261; y = (0.831, 0.169)
  2) SOME_VALUE > -10.5
...
```

How do I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: It's not going to be so easy because all `print.BinaryTree` method does basically is printing `my_tree@tree` while adding some comments above.

Comment: Is there a way to simply extract the values?  I'd be fine manually joining it back together later if I have to.  I'm just looking for some programmatic method to obtain them other than manually copying from a plot.

Comment: Yes, see my answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/171317/42632) where I show exactly how you can achieve this pragmatically. See also the other answer by the package creator himself (Prof. Zeileis) on how to do this using the newer `partykit` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do this with the `partykit` package (the successor to `party`) but even there it requires some hacking. In principle, the `print()` function is customizable with panel functions for inner and terminal nodes etc. But they do not look very nice even for seemingly simple tasks like this one.

As you appear to have used a tree with a bivariate response, let's consider this simple (albeit not very meaningful) reproducible example:

```
library("partykit")
airq <- subset(airquality, !is.na(Ozone))
ct <- ctree(Ozone + Wind ~ ., data = airq)
```

For the inner nodes let's assume we just want to show the p-value that is readily available in the `$info` of each node. We can format this via:

```
ip <- function(node) formatinfo_node(node,
  prefix = " ",
  FUN = function(info) paste0("[p = ", format.pval(info$p.value), "]")
)
```

For the terminal nodes we want to show the number of observations (assuming no `weights` have been used) and the mean response. Both are pre-computed in small tables and then accessed via the `$id` of each node:

```
n <- table(ct$fitted[["(fitted)"]])
m <- aggregate(ct$fitted[["(response)"]], list(ct$fitted[["(fitted)"]]), mean)
m <- apply(m[, -1], 1, function(x) paste(round(x, digits = 3), collapse = ", "))
names(m) <- names(n)
```

The panel function is then defined by:

```
tp <- function(node) formatinfo_node(node,
  prefix = ": ",
  FUN = function(info) paste0(
    "n = ", n[as.character(node$id)],
    ", y = (", m[as.character(node$id)], ")"
  )
)
```

To apply this in the `print()` method we need to call `print.party()` directly because currently `print.constparty()` does not pass this on correctly. (We will have to fix this in the `partykit` package.)

```
print.party(ct, inner_panel = ip, terminal_panel = tp)
## [1] root
## |   [2] Temp <= 82 [p = 0.0044842]
## |   |   [3] Temp <= 77: n = 52, y = (18.615, 11.562)
## |   |   [4] Temp > 77: n = 27, y = (41.815, 9.737)
## |   [5] Temp > 82: n = 37, y = (75.405, 7.565)
```

This is hopefully close to what you wanted to do and should give you a template for further modifications.

Comment: Fantastic!  This is exactly what I'm looking for!