# Add horizontal line to terminal barplots in party / partykit trees

Tags: r, tree, party

I am using the `ctree` function from `partykit`.

```
library(rpart)
library(partykit)

fit <- ctree(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data=kyphosis)
plot(fit, terminal_panel=node_barplot)
```

[image]

I want to add an additional horizonal line to each barplot, indicating the average reponse across the dataset, i.e. at 0.79 here.

```
prop.table(table(kyphosis$Kyphosis))

    absent   present 
 0.7901235 0.2098765
```

**Approach**: I started to modify the `node_barplot` function that is passed to the `terminal_panel` argument. But the source code is very long and comes with almost no comments. So I tried to go step by step, stripping down the function to its first two lines of code (plus an extra print command). However, if I run it, the object `y` is `NULL` and an error is thrown.

```
node_barplot2 <- function(obj, ...)
{   
  y <- obj$fitted[["(response)"]]   # first lime from node_barplot source
  print(y)
  stopifnot(is.factor(y) || isTRUE(all.equal(round(y), y)) || is.data.frame(y))
}

plot(fit, terminal_panel=node_barplot2)

> Error in round(y) : Non-numeric argument in mathematical function
```

As its the original code, I do not quite see **where I go wrong here** and **how  I could draw the horizontal line**. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `partykit` distinguishes "panel" functions and "panel-generating" functions:

- The former just expect the `node` of a tree as their sole argument and then draw this node (using `grid` graphics).
- The latter expect a full tree as their first argument plus further arguments for customization. They return a "panel" function (with only argument `node`) where certain informations like the x and y ranges are stored in the function environment.

To signal that a function is a panel-generating function, it has to have class `"grapcon_generator"`. Hence

```
class(node_barplot)
## [1] "grapcon_generator"
```

To add certain graphical elements to the function, I would recommend copying the whole `node_barplot` source code (including the class assignment at the end) and then add the elements you need, e.g., a horizontal reference line you can draw with `grid.lines()`.

Comment: Thanks @AchimZeileis ! I totally failed to notice the difference between the two.... BTW: I love partykits' graphical features! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness: As Achim explained, the class attribute was not correct to indicate that the function has to be passed the whole tree, not just a node. Setting it to `class(node_barplot2) <- "grapcon_generator"` does the trick.

I slightly tweaked the `node_barplot` code and added two new arguments to the function: `hline` and `h.gp`. The first one specifies where the horizontal line is drawn (a value between 0 and 1). The line is the same across all terminal panels. The second one takes a `gpar` object used to style the drawn line. The function is named `node_barplot2`, you can find the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/markheckmann/0313362f0c84b21625bd). The code that draws the line is at the end.

**Example**

```
library(devtools)
source_gist("0313362f0c84b21625bd")

plot(fit, terminal_panel = node_barplot2, 
     tp_args= list(hline = .8, 
                   h.gp = gpar(lwd=4, col="blue")))
```

[image]