# Add barplots to circles in inner nodes in partykit plotted trees

Tags: r, plot, party

The `partykit` package plots barplots at the terminal nodes of trees which gives a visual rendition of the posterior probabilities of the dependent variable classes.

I would like to add those barplots also in the inner nodes, below the standard circles/ellipses. This needs to use a function that is a mixture of `node_inner()` and `node_barplot()` to the `inner_panel` argument of the `plot()` method.

But those function have pretty complex internals and I'm not sure how to mix the two in order to have to inner plots stacked vertically.

Any ideas?

Comment: like this?`ct <- ctree(factor(cyl) ~ ., data = mtcars, minsplit = 2); plot(ct, inner_panel = node_barplot(ct))`

Comment: nope, this is what it is plotted if you just unse node_barplot. I was trying to join both node_inner and node_barplot in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, it just doesn't look very appealing. If you want to show the name of the splitting variable and the p-value, it would be better to tweak the `mainlab` argument of `node_barplot`. In the answer to 
[Ctree classification with weights - results displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27260838/ctree-classification-with-weights-results-displayed#27261838) there is in illustration how to include weights in the title - in a similar fashion you could display splitting variable and p-value.

If you are determined to set up a new panel function that has two subpanels, you need a little bit of `grid` programming (the graphics system that the `plot()` method is based on). You need to set up a `grid.layout` and then go through the resulting `viewport`s.

```
make_inner_and_barplot <- function(object, ...) {
  function(node) {  
    ## layout
    pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(nrow = 2, ncol = 1,
      heights = unit(c(0.2, 0.8), "npc"))))
    ## background color
    grid.rect(gp = gpar(fill = "white", col = 0))
    ## circle
    pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col = 1, layout.pos.row = 1))
    node_inner(object)(node)
    popViewport()
    ## circle
    pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col = 1, layout.pos.row = 2))
    node_barplot(object, id = FALSE, ...)(node)
    popViewport(2)
  }
}
```

With the resulting panel function you can then do:

```
ct <- ctree(factor(cyl) ~ ., data = mtcars, minsplit = 2)
plot(ct, inner_panel = make_inner_and_barplot(ct), tnex = 0.8)
```

[image: inner and barplot]